# Cycling over an array in Kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, iterator

Is there in Kotlin something like Cycle Iterator from Guava library?

[https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect
/Iterators.html#cycle(java.lang.Iterable)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#cycle(java.lang.Iterable))

I want to cycle an array, like:

```
1 2 3 4
4 1 2 3
3 4 1 2
```

...

If possible with native Kotlin or well-accepted libraries.

I won't like to add Guava to my codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `slice()` on the array:

```
array = arrayOf(array.last()) + array.sliceArray(0 until array.size - 1)
```

rearranges the array by putting the last item in the 1st position and shifting the rest to the right.

```
var array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

(0 until array.size).forEach {
    array.forEach { print(it.toString() + " ") }
    println()
    array = arrayOf(array.last()) + array.sliceArray(0 until array.size - 1)
}
```

will print:

```
1 2 3 4 
4 1 2 3 
3 4 1 2 
2 3 4 1
```

The same result can be achieved with:

```
array = arrayOf(array.last()) + array.filterIndexed { index, _ ->  index < array.size - 1 }.toTypedArray()
```

This extension function:

```
fun <T> Array<T>.rightCycle(d: Int): Array<T> {
    val n = d % size
    if (n == 0) return this
    return sliceArray(size - n until size) + sliceArray(0 until size - n)
}
```

can be used to cycle any array `d` places each time:

```
var array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

(0 until array.size).forEach {
    array.forEach { print(it.toString() + " ") }
    println()
    array = array.rightCycle(2)
}
```

will print:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
5 6 1 2 3 4 
3 4 5 6 1 2 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
5 6 1 2 3 4 
3 4 5 6 1 2
```

Comment: this should help

Answer (score 1):

```
fun IntArray.pivoted(p: Int): IntArray = sliceArray(p until size) + sliceArray(0 until p)
```

Can be used for example like this (right rotation):

```
(array.size downTo 1).forEach {
    println(array.pivoted(it).joinToString())
}
```

or

```
val cycles = (0 until array.size).map {
    array.pivoted(array.size - it)
}
```

or like this (left rotation)

```
val cycles = (0 until array.size).map {
    array.pivoted(it)
}
```

to be sent to the console in the standard fashion

```
for (cycle in cycles) {
    println(cycle.joinToString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a bit and check other answers I implemented a version too, using `subList` from `MutableList`:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.rotate(): MutableList<T> {
    val subList = this.toMutableList().subList(0, this.size - 1)
    subList.add(0, this.last())
    return subList
}



class BuildLeagueTournamentTest {


    @Test
    fun testInvoke() {
        val teams = createTeams()
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(intArrayOf(1,2,3,4), teams.toIntArray())

        var newTeams = teams.rotate()
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(intArrayOf(1,2,3,4), teams.toIntArray())
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(intArrayOf(4,1,2,3), newTeams.toIntArray())

        newTeams = newTeams.rotate()
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(intArrayOf(3,4,1,2), newTeams.toIntArray())

    }

    private fun createTeams(): MutableList<Int> {
        return mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    }
}
```